# Defining Languages Available at boot - LiveCD

Tags: linux, filesystems, boot, mount, iso

I am trying to create a refined version of the buggy [uck](http://uck.sourceforge.net) for customizing Ubuntu LiveCD ISO, [here](https://github.com/miroamr78/UCK2) it is if you're interested in helping.

**NOTE:** The process is straight-forward, except when customizing on-boot locale languages.

I read that isolinux tweaks could help in doing that, but I don't know how. I don't want advanced customization of languages, I just want two options:

1. Specify a set of languages that are supported in the booting environment.
2. Specify a default language among them.

Is that possible?

Comment: You want to be able to provide a list to the user as they use the LiveCD so that they can pick their approp. locale/lang?

Comment: This link might help with what you're trying to do: https://anonymous-proxy-servers.net/en/help/jondo-live-cd1.html

Comment: @slm: exactly, that's what I want to do ..

Comment: Does the link not show you how to do this, or to see how they were able to do so? I'd download it and take a peek at their isolinux setup on their LiveCD.

Comment: @slm: The link shows how to do that manually, I want to actually **remove** all the unnecessary boot languages and choose one as the default as a boot option by scripting the functionality ..

Comment: @slm: After peeking in the isolinux directory on a standard ubuntu iso, I found it contains language files, such as: en.tr and en.hlp for english (for ex), the *.hlp files seem to be for windows help, the other file seems to be for translation. I think if I deleted **all** windows help files, and the .tr files for unneeded languages that would do the trick .. what do you think ?

Comment: I'd try it but I'm 1/2 suspecting that there's a config file that lists them out too.

Comment: @slm: I'll look for that ...

Comment: @slm: The preseed folder has a configuration file called cli.seed, it seems to mention language packs, but it doesn't contain any listings. Strange ..